# Excel macro to combine two excel rows by matching two columns

Tags: vba, excel

How can I match the names from two columns and if they are the same then merge the two lines. Meaning if first_name and last_name are the same then combine the rows (since they are presumably the same person). If the other cells in the row are the same I want them to just combine. If they are different, I want both values/strings saved by leaving them both in the combined cell with a comma between them.

So this:

```
First  Last     Number   Sign
Joe    White    1122     Scorpio
Joe    White    1144     Scorpio
Joe    Jones    11445    Leo
David  White    112      Virgo
```

Should turn into this:

```
First       Last        Number       Sign
Joe         White        1122, 1144  Scorpio
Joe         Jones        11445       Leo
David       White        112         Virgo
```

Since the first two lines have a match between Joe White and Joe White (both first and last name are the same) the two lines get combined. Since the Number column has different values, they get combined in the one cell with a comma delimitation. Because the Sign, in this case Scorpio, is the same it just gets combined without listing both (duplicate) values. In the case of the third and fourth name, only one of the names matches (either White or Joe) so they do not get combined at all since both names have to match.

Comment: concatenate two columns in both files and then merge lines

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I'm new here and I don't know what to search for. Can you point me to something that would do this?

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak: I concat the two columns but then how do I merge it? It doesn't seem to do what I pointed to above?

Answer (score 0):

OK Dsine here is a suggestion.  Part of the spirit of SO is that you should demonstrate and share what you have already tried at the moment.
A starting point could be to write down in words how you might go about solving your problem, try to code it and research your gaps.  See my comments in the code below as a possible example.  If you are still stuck. and then post your question.

So a starter for ten could be as follows:

```
Sub concat()

Dim sdRow As Long, sdcol As Long, ldRow As Long, ldCol As Long
Dim rowNo As Long, resultRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim keyVal As String

'assume original data is in Sheets("Data")
'assume result data is in Sheets("Data2")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Data")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Data2")

'original data block r/c
sdRow = 2
sdcol = 1
ldRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ldCol = ws1.Cells(sdRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'assume result data set in Sheets("Data2") is placed in same sheet position
'as in Sheets("Data") and copy headings
ws1.Activate
ws1.Range(Cells(sdRow, sdcol), Cells(sdRow, ldCol)).Copy _
Destination:=ws2.Cells(sdRow, sdcol)

'sort original data
 ws1.Activate
    ws1.Range(Cells(sdRow, sdcol), Cells(ldRow, ldCol)).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Columns(sdcol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=Columns(sdcol + 1), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'loop through original data
rowNo = sdRow + 1
resultRow = rowNo

Do While rowNo < ldRow
    'Test if names are the same
    keyVal = Cells(rowNo, sdcol) & Cells(rowNo, sdcol + 1)
        If keyVal = Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol) & Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol + 1) Then
            'copy data row to Sheet("Data2")
            ws1.Range(Cells(rowNo, sdcol), Cells(rowNo, ldCol)).Copy _
            Destination:=ws2.Cells(resultRow, sdcol)

            'modify 'Number' cell in Sheet("Data2") if required
                If ws1.Cells(rowNo, sdcol + 2) = ws1.Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol + 2) Then
                    'do nothing
                Else
                    ws2.Cells(resultRow, sdcol + 2) = Str(ws1.Cells(rowNo, sdcol + 2)) & "," & Str(ws1.Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol + 2))
                End If

             'modify 'Sign' cell in Sheet("Data2") if required
                If ws1.Cells(rowNo, sdcol + 3) = ws1.Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol + 3) Then
                    'do nothing
                Else
                    ws2.Cells(resultRow, sdcol + 3) = ws1.Cells(rowNo, sdcol + 3) & "," & ws1.Cells(rowNo + 1, sdcol + 3)
                End If

            resultRow = resultRow + 1

        Else
            'copy data 'as is' to Sheet("Data2")
            ws1.Range(Cells(rowNo, sdcol), Cells(rowNo, ldCol)).Copy _
            Destination:=ws2.Cells(resultRow, sdcol)

            resultRow = resultRow + 1

        End If

    rowNo = rowNo + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your explanation and starter.

Comment: That's good.  If this meets your requirements then perhaps you would mark it as 'answer' to tidy off this thread.